# is it possible to load BackTrack 5 on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: penetration-testing, raspberry-pi

I am thinking about loading Back Track 5 on the [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/quick-start-guide) and was wondering if this is possible or am I setting myself up for wasting a lot of time?

The [ARM version of BackTrack5](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/downloads/) is ~1 GB whereas the ["Squeeze" Debian](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/debian/6/debian6-19-04-2012/debian6-19-04-2012.zip) version recommended by Raspberry Pi folks is 443 MB.

I have an 8GB SD card which I will use to copy BackTrack on to and attempt to load on the Raspberry Pi. But I'm just wondering if this is possible or if anyone has tried this before.  Would appreciate all / any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you should be aware of is the booting process of the pi. You have to have a fully working boot partition (vfat) on a SD card to start it. So installing becomes a problem, because you cannot boot from another media than the one you want to install it on.

It may be possible to create a separate installation partition and install from there, but this seems messy.

The other alternatives I can think of is installing using a VM or making a .img the way raspian does it.

Good luck! I would love to have BackTrack working on the pi!

Comment: Thanks piksel.  I also found this thread relevant. http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=47371

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot to mention the instruction set. That's an even larger obstacle. But since a lot of people have the pi and already some of them wants to put BT on them, chances are someone will make it work.

Comment: Yep.  In the mean time, we can use this: http://blog.pwnieexpress.com/post/24967860602/raspberry-pwn-a-pentesting-release-for-the-raspberry

Answer (score 4):

and now the successor to Back Track, Kali, has full support for Raspberry Pi:

http://www.kali.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

You can't without a lot of work.

Surely what [piksel bitworks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/910069/piksel-bitworks) reported in his answer is true, but it should be okay to install it from an prepared image using your own computer to write to the SD card.

The main point, in my opinion, is that you would have to get Backtrack's code and compile it yourself. You would not be able to use the image file provided as ARM Backtrack because it seems to be compiled for ARMv7, while Raspberry PI has a ARM11 CPU, which means that it has ARMv6 Architecture ([Raspberry PI hardware](http://elinux.org/RaspberryPiBoard#Hardware)).

Installing the software you are really going to use into a Raspberry Pi compatible distro seems far more effective to me, and probably it would also help you better use the available resources.

Answer (score 0):

Pi's can run linux, rather then installing BT 5 just install the tools. Either that or use one of the various Pi distros that have many of the same tools installed such as:http://blog.pwnieexpress.com/post/24967860602/raspberry-pwn-a-pentesting-release-for-the-raspberry or http://sourceforge.net/projects/pwnpi/